# How to split sentences in a dataframe by dot to build another dataframe but keeping sentence ID

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a dataframe with `ID` and `TEXT`field.  I want to create another dataframe ***splitting the sentences in `TEXT` field by the*** `dot` and keeping the original `ID`

So the phrase:  **"I loves cats. I hate snakes"** becomes `two sentences in 2 rows` in the new dataframe:

```
0 `I love cats`
0 `I hate snakes`
```

Original Dataframe:

```
ID                      TEXT
1    This is a msg. Another msg
2    The weather is hot, the water is cold. My hands are freezing
```

Transformed Dataframe:

```
ID
1      This is a msg
1      Another msg
2      The weather is hot, the water is cold
2      My hands are freezing
```

the code to build the dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,2], 'TEXT':['This is a msg. Another msg', 'The weather is hot, the water is cold. My hands are freezing']})
```

I am trying to use `split` -> `df['TEXT'].astype(str).split('.')` but I keep getting errors because series objects has no split method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to set `ID` as index beforehand so that the exploded rows will have the respective IDs

```
df.set_index('ID', inplace=True)
split = df['TEXT'].str.split('.').explode()
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `df['TEXT'].astype(str).split('.')`

try: `df['TEXT'].str.split('.').explode()`

Comment: you suggestion works. Now i get a list [This is a msg,  Another msg]  and I need it in different rows, but keeping the ID.  I am getting a hard time to do it ;-(

Comment: thanks @gtomer.  I can't cast  vote to your answer beacuse I am new the stackoverflow, but you helped a lot. Nuri tas answer solved my problem completely due the set_index operations that I was missing.  Huge thanks tho.